# Hibernate saving one to one objects

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, primefaces

I'm developing a small wab project with Netbeans 7.4, Maven, JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.0, Hibernate 3.6.10 and Spring 3.2.3.

I have these MySQL tables/relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `usu_nick` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `usu_pass` varchar(20) default NULL,  
  `usu_rol` char(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`usu_nick`),
  KEY `usu_rol` (`usu_rol`)
) ENGINE = innodb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `rol_cod` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `rol_per` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `rol_des` varchar(25) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`rol_cod`),
  KEY `rol_per` (`rol_per`)
) ENGINE = innodb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `permisos` (
  `per_cod` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `per_des` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `per_lvl` tinyint default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`per_cod`)
) ENGINE = innodb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `datosusu` (
  `datosusu_cod` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `datosusu_fecalta` date default NULL,
  `datosusu_fecbaja` date default NULL,
  `datosusu_nomfisc` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `datosusu_nomcomer` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `datosusu_nifcif` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `datosusu_contacto` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `datosusu_tlfempre` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `datosusu_tlfparti` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `datosusu_fax` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `datosusu_mailempre` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `datosusu_mailparti` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `datosusu_dir` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `datosusu_cp` varchar(5) default NULL,
  `datosusu_localidad` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `datosusu_prov` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `datosusu_zona` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `datosusu_tipo` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `datosusu_titular` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `datosusu_sucur` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `datosusu_ccc` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `datosusu_web` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `datosusu_cargo` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `datosusu_foto` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `datosusu_des` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `datosusu_lat` double default NULL,
  `datosusu_lon` double default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`datosusu_cod`),
  KEY `datosusu_prov` (`datosusu_prov`),
  KEY `datosusu_zona` (`datosusu_zona`),
  KEY `datosusu_tipo` (`datosusu_tipo`)
) ENGINE = innodb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usuarios_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`usu_rol`) REFERENCES `roles` (`rol_cod`);



ALTER TABLE `roles`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `roles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rol_per`) REFERENCES `permisos` (`per_cod`);  



ALTER TABLE `datosusu`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `datosusu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`datosusu_cod`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`usu_nick`);  

ALTER TABLE `datosusu`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `datosusu_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`datosusu_prov`) REFERENCES `provincias` (`prov_cod`);  

ALTER TABLE `datosusu`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `datosusu_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`datosusu_zona`) REFERENCES `zonas` (`zon_cod`); 

ALTER TABLE `datosusu`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `datosusu_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`datosusu_tipo`) REFERENCES `tiposnegocio` (`tiposnegocio_cod`);
```

These are the HBM.XNL files:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="backingbeans.Datosusu" table="datosusu" catalog="apec">
        <id name="datosusuCod" type="string">
            <column name="datosusu_cod" length="25" />
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">usuarios</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="tiposnegocio" class="backingbeans.Tiposnegocio" fetch="select">
            <column name="datosusu_tipo" length="3" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="provincias" class="backingbeans.Provincias" fetch="select">
            <column name="datosusu_prov" length="2" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="zonas" class="backingbeans.Zonas" fetch="select">
            <column name="datosusu_zona" length="3" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <one-to-one name="usuarios" class="backingbeans.Usuarios" constrained="true"></one-to-one>
        <property name="datosusuFecalta" type="date">
            <column name="datosusu_fecalta" length="10" />
        </property>
REST OF FIELD DEFINITIONS...

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="backingbeans.Usuarios" table="usuarios" catalog="apec">
        <id name="usuNick" type="string">
            <column name="usu_nick" length="25" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="roles" class="backingbeans.Roles" fetch="select">
            <column name="usu_rol" length="3" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="usuPass" type="string">
            <column name="usu_pass" length="20" />
        </property>
        <set name="mensajesesForSmsDest" table="mensajes" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="sms_dest" length="25" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="backingbeans.Mensajes" />
        </set>
        <one-to-one name="datosusu" class="backingbeans.Datosusu"></one-to-one>
        <set name="mensajesesForSmsUsu" table="mensajes" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="sms_usu" length="25" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="backingbeans.Mensajes" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem occurs when I try to create a new User-DatosUsu. When ALL data is fulfilled in the web view I call 2 functions in a spring web service to save them:

```
    public void setNuevoUsuario(Usuarios elUsuario){

    Session sesion=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
    try {                             
        sesion.beginTransaction();         
        sesion.saveOrUpdate((Usuarios)sesion.merge(elUsuario)); 
        sesion.getTransaction().commit(); 
        sesion.close();                 
    }
     catch (HibernateException he) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error salvando el USUARIO.", null));
        sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
        sesion.close();
        }    
    }


public void setNuevoDatosUsu(Datosusu losDatosUsu){

    Session sesion=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
    try {                             
        sesion.beginTransaction();         
        Datosusu datosTemp=(Datosusu)sesion.merge(losDatosUsu);
        sesion.saveOrUpdate(datosTemp); 
        sesion.getTransaction().commit(); 
        sesion.close();                 
    }
     catch (HibernateException he) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error salvando los DATOSUSU.", null));
        sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
        sesion.close();
        }    
    }
```

The 2 Hibernate objects are detached so that's why I merge them.
When I try to execute the above code the User is inserted correctly in the DB.
But when I try to insert the Datosusu this error happens:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier
    at org.hibernate.engine.EntityKey.<init>(EntityKey.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.type.OneToOneType.isNull(OneToOneType.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:433)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:600)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)
    at backingbeans.ServicioImpl.setNuevoDatosUsu(ServicioImpl.java:254)
    at backingbeans.AltaBB.salvaUsuario(AltaBB.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at     javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 27 more
```

This is the procedure that calls the 2 procedures that save the data:

```
 public String salvaUsuario() {                    

        //fulfill the user with rest of fields
        elUsuario.setRoles(new Roles("NOR", new Permisos("NOR")));

        //fulfill rest of fields of losDatos 
        losDatos.setProvincias(new Provincias(elPais));
        losDatos.setZonas(new Zonas(laZona));
        losDatos.setTiposnegocio(new Tiposnegocio(elTipoNegocio));
        losDatos.setDatosusuFecbaja(null);
        losDatos.setDatosusuFecalta(new Date());
        losDatos.setDatosusuCod(elUsuario.getUsuNick());

        //fulfill references
        losDatos.setUsuarios(elUsuario);                
        elUsuario.setDatosusu(losDatos);

        //save both
        elServicio.setNuevoUsuario(elUsuario);
        elServicio.setNuevoDatosUsu(losDatos);

        return "login";
    }
```

I Don't understand why this is happening. As far as I'm concerned all data is correctly fulfilled. I'm a beginner with Hibernate.
May someone with more experience help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I found it.
The only problem with my code were the lines:

Datosusu datosTemp=(Datosusu)sesion.merge(losDatosUsu);
sesion.saveOrUpdate(datosTemp);

Instead I used:

sesion.persist(losDatosUsu);

Could someone explain me the diference between merge and persist?
Thanks!

Comment: When you persist a new entity the entity will be persisted and managed. If the entity already exists in db `EntityExistsException` will be throws.
If you merge a new entity the entity will be persisted and managed. If the entity already exists, new state merged with old state (entity will be update).

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line within the second class mapping backingbeans.Usuarios :-

```
<class name="backingbeans.Usuarios" table="usuarios" catalog="apec">
        <id name="usuNick" type="string">
            <column name="usu_nick" length="25" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
<one-to-one name="datosusu" class="backingbeans.Datosusu" />
....
....
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi Manjunath, the line "<one-to-one name="datosusu" class="backingbeans.Datosusu" />" is already in the Usuarios.HBM.XML file. It is just in the middle. Any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: @JesusSchneider Sorry I missed that out. It looks like you are trying to save Usuarios and Datosusu entities seperately. This I feel is causing the issue because the Id of Datosusu is specified as <generated class="foreign"> which would mean it needs to be supplied with the same Id of the Usuarios entity. You need to set Usuarios entity to Datosusu and the same Datosusu to Usuarios by using the setters and then save only Usuarios. If it still doesnot work then  please make the change <one-to-one name="datosusu" class="backingbeans.Datosusu" cascade="save-update"></one-to-one> and try it.

Comment: Hi again Manjunath!
Ok, the log indicates me that there's some error with the key, but I don't understand WHY. 
I have tried to fulfill ALL fields in both classes and save just the "Usuarios". I have also tried to add the "cascade="save-update"" to the Datosusu.hbm.xml. 
I cannot create a Datosusu no matter what I try! It should be possible to create and save a new Datosusu without any special configuration. Any help please? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So now you are getting a different error with key. Please paste it in ur question. Also if possible pls paste the code where in u are creating the Usuarios and Datosus objects. Additionally turn on the SQL logging by setting the show_sql for hibernate session factory and see what are the insert statements generated. If you have set the cascade type then ideally 2 insert statements should get fired.

Comment: I think I didn't express myself properly. The error is the same as before. I have added above the code where I call both save functions, as you can see nothing special. About the hibernate HQL just one appears, the insert of the user, I thinks that the next HQL triggers the error. Any idea? I think I'm trying to do a very common operation, so it cannot be so difficult.. Thanks!!